# Two setIntervals activating in a sequence to change CSS

Tags: javascript, beginner, css, dom, simon-says

I'm making a Simon game and I made this function to show flashing lights:

```
 //a random array representing html divs to change colors
 game.computerMoves = [green, red, blue, red, green, green , yellow];

function showMoves() {

let i = -1;
let c = -1;

const start = setInterval(function() {
    if (i >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {
        clearInterval(start);
    }

    console.log(i + 'start ' + game.computerMoves.length);

    const showColors = new Map([
        [green, 'lime'],
        [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
        [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
        [red, 'salmon'],
    ]);

    i++;

    let move = game.computerMoves[i];

    move.style.backgroundColor = showColors.get(move);
    //revert the colors that were changed in showMoves
    //put at 2 seconds to change after showMoves is done
    const stop = setTimeout(function() {

        console.log(c + 'stop ' + game.computerMoves.length);

        if (c >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(stop);

        }
        const colorKey = new Map([
            [green, 'green'],
            [yellow, 'rgb(204,204,0)'],
            [red, 'red'],
            [blue, 'blue']
        ]);

        c++;

        let move = game.computerMoves[c];

        move.style.backgroundColor = colorKey.get(move);
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is good code or not but it works how I want it to and I would appreciate any feedback.

edit- here is my html and css, its not done though https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/JLBpNQ

Comment: Is there any chance you could include your HTML and CSS code so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: Sure but i'm not finished with it. - https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/JLBpNQ

Answer (score 2):

What is the `game` object for? I assume it's for keeping all game states together, which is good, but I can't tell from this example.

```
let i = -1;
let c = -1;
```

It's a bit strange to start an index at -1. The names also tells me nothing about what these are. This also makes it hard to follow the exact flow of the code.

```
const showColors = new Map ...
```

You are creating a new map for every loop (same with `colorKey`). These should be declared once, at the start of your program. You could use the `game` object for this.

```
if (i >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {
    clearInterval(start);
}
```

You are stopping the interval from future calls, but not the current function you are in, which gives an error, since the index is out of bound. Add a `return` to stop it.

```
clearInterval(stop);
```

When the timeout is done, you are clearing the same timeout, which is already done, so this does nothing. You can get rid of it.

You can make a function to turn on or off a light. You can then pass this directly to your timeout. This also gets rid of `c`.

```
function setLight(color, isOn) {
    color.style.backgroundColor = isOn ? game.showColors.get(color) : game.colorKey.get(color);
}
```

The full code then looks like this. I had to make up some HTML, CSS and a few lines of JS to initialize some things, since you didn't include it.

```js
const red = document.getElementById('red');
const green = document.getElementById('green');
const yellow = document.getElementById('yellow');
const blue = document.getElementById('blue'); 
let game = {};

game.showColors = new Map([
    [green, 'lime'],
    [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
    [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
    [red, 'salmon'],
]);
game.colorKey = new Map([
    [green, 'green'],
    [yellow, 'rgb(204,204,0)'],
    [blue, 'blue'],
    [red, 'red']
]);

//a random array representing html divs to change colors
game.computerMoves = [green, red, blue, red, green, green , yellow];

showMoves();

function showMoves() {
    let i = 0;

    const start = setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
            clearInterval(start);
            return;
        }

        const move = game.computerMoves[i];
        setLight(move, true);
        setTimeout(setLight.bind(null, move, false), 1000); //Using bind to preset arguments
        
        i++;
    }, 2000);
}

function setLight(color, isOn) {
    color.style.backgroundColor = isOn ? game.showColors.get(color) : game.colorKey.get(color);
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#red {background-color: red;}
#green {background-color: green;}
#yellow {background-color: rgb(204,204,0);}
#blue {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Never use `setInterval`.

- Don't use `clearTimeout`, or `clearInterval`, and with that don't use `setInterval` as it can not be stopped without using `clearInterval`.  There is a long list of reasons not to use intervals but the best reason is you don't need to keep a handle to timer events.
- If you use the same object which you create via a function call each iteration of your code, you should create it once outside the function. This will reduce both memory and CPU overhead. In your code that would be the two maps you use, `showColors` and `colorKey`
- If you require a series of timed events create the next timeout inside the event. If the sequence is complete simply don't create the next event.
- Learn to use boolean math and the bitwise operators as they can simplify a great many common tasks. In the rewrite I use the shift right operator `>>` to shift bits of the `moveCounter` right one bit. This is the same as `Math.floor(moveCounter / 2)` I also use the and operator `&` to mask the lowest bit using it to toggle between the two color maps. In this case it is equivilent to `(moveCounter % 2)` as `moveCounter` is an integer value. However more acuratly the operation is `Math.floor(moveCounter % 2)`
- Your logic for the counters `i` and `c` is a little over complicated. Start them at 0 and the statement `if (i >= game.computerMoves.length - 1) {` can be simplified by moving it after the `i++` operation and changing it to `if (i === game.computerMoves.length) {`
- Without the HTML and CSS it is hard to comment but ut could be mush better to use CSS rules to set the background color using `move.className` to set the element's class directly or via the `move.classList` to either `toggle` or`add` and `remove` class names.

### The rewrite

I have moved the color maps outside the function so they do not need to be created each time. I have put them into and array so we can use the bottom bit of the `moveCounter` to select the appropriate map.

The sequence is a set of timeout events, each called from within the other. The sequence ends when the `moveCounter` reaches the `timeoutCount`

```js
const colors = [
    new Map([[green, "lime"], [yellow, "#FF6"], [blue, "dodgerblue"], [red, "salmon"]]),
    new Map([[green, "green"], [yellow, "#CC0"], [red, "red"], [blue, "blue"]])
];
const colorFlashPeriod = 1000; // in ms
function showMoves() {
    var moveCounter = 0; 
    const timeoutCount = game.computerMoves.length * 2; 
    (function nextColor() {
        var move = game.computerMoves[moveCounter >> 1]; 
        move.style.backgroundColor = colors[(moveCounter++) & 1].get(move);
        if (moveCounter < timeoutCount) { setTimeout(nextColor, colorFlashPeriod) }
    })();
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree that `moveCounter >> 1` is better than `Math.floor(moveCounter / 2)`. Sure, your code is smaller, but it hurts readability. `setInterval` also (rarely) has it's place.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Every coder should know how all the bitwise operators work. If not then they MUST learn how they work. I will not dumb down my code for the very few ignorant who refuse to learn. If you can come up with a scenario where timeout can not do what interval can please do tell. setInterval functionality is browser dependent and should not be used.

Comment: Dumbing down your code != using readable code. Citation needed for browser dependent. MDN doesn't note anything. Sure, you can use `setTimeout` for everything, but it's not always necessary.

Comment: in const timeoutCount why are you multiplying game.computerMoves.length times 2? And wont moveCount >> 1 always equal 0? how will it get to anything but whats in the 0 place of the array if it always equals 0?

Comment: @kokokonoi No `n>>1` is a the same as integer divide by 2 ie `0b0111` (7) becomes `0b0011` (3). It moves all the bits to the right by one. I multiply by 2 as there are a total of `2 * computerMoves.length length` events 1 second apart

Comment: in function nextColor in the if statement (moveCounter) will always be 0 because its not being raised anywhere but in move.style.backgroundColor, so how is the setTimout stopped? also isn't setTimeout the same as setInterval? should I use setTimeout over setInterval?

Comment: @kokokonoi ?? you point out where `moveCounter` is incremented  The sequenced is stopped by not calling the next timeout when not `moveCounter < timeoutCount`  You should use setTimeout it is simpler and will not create event stacking (many event firing in quick succession) if there is blocking code. Nor can you be sure what interval will do if you switch browser tabs.

Comment: alright I think I understand the code now. thanks a lot for the response I really appreciate it!